# C Program Skipping if Statements Even When Conditions Are Met

Tags: if-statement, statements

Trying to solve this question I have for HW but I'm stuck with one little problem. I have a series of *if* statements but the program just skips every if statement even when the condition is met. Ex: User wants to execute 5 - 2, instead of going to the second *if* statement to check for when the user entered the minus, the program just skips every single *if* statement.

The question is:

> Consider a C program that reads two real numbers from the keyboard
>   followed by a character where the character can be one of the
>   operators +, -, *, /, or % providing the addition, subtraction,
>   multiplication, division, or remainder respectively. Then the result
>   is displayed on the screen. For example, if the user types:
>   2.0 3.0 % then your code will display: 2 % 3 = 2 Note: In the above example the inputs are real numbers but the remainder only performs an
>   integer operation. Hence, the two real numbers must be type cast to
>   allow computation by remainder. In the case where an invalid operator
>   is entered (e.g. $) then an error message is printed to the standard
>   output, e.g. Invalid entry!

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){

  double num1, num2, plus, minus, divide, mult, op;

  printf("Enter two numbers and an operation you would like to perform on those number: \n");
  scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &num1, &num2, &op);
  if(op=='+')
  {
    plus=(num1 + num2);
    printf("%lf + %lf = %lf", num1, num2, plus);
  }
  else if(op=='-')
  {
    minus=num1-num2;
    printf("%lf - %lf = %lf", num1, num2, minus);
  }
  else if(op=='/')
  {
    divide=num1/num2;
    printf("%lf / %lf = %lf", num1, num2, divide);
  }
  else if(op=='%')
  {
    int num1, num2, remain;
    remain= (num1%num2);
    printf("%d %% %d = %d", num1, num2, remain);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Invalid entry!");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Would really appreciate some help on this, have been struggling for a while on such a small error.

Comment: You are declaring op as a double, it should be a char.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting the line

```
  printf("op=%lf\n",op);
```

right below your `scanf` statement to see what value `op` has for different operations.  That solves the mystery of why the `if` statements were being skipped.

Then, as `@l-l` suggests, try declaring `op` as `char op;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double num1, num2, plus, minus, divide, mult, op;
    char operation;   
    printf("Enter first number");
    scanf("%lf", &num1);
    printf("Enter second number");
    scanf("%lf", &num2);
    printf("Enter operation");
    scanf(" %c", &operation);

     if(operation=='+')
    {
        plus=(num1 + num2);
        printf("%lf + %lf = %lf", num1, num2, plus);
    }
     if(operation=='-')
    {
        plus=(num1 - num2);
        printf("%lf - %lf = %lf", num1, num2, plus);
    }
     if(operation=='/')
    {
        plus=(num1 / num2);
        printf("%lf / %lf = %lf", num1, num2, plus);
    }
     if(operation=='*')
    {
        plus=(num1 * num2);
        printf("%lf * %lf = %lf", num1, num2, plus);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Try this. The code compiled and working fine.